# Syntax highlighting in zsh using 256 colors?

Tags: colors, syntax-highlighting, zsh, prezto

I'm using prezto with zsh, and my difficulty is with the syntax highlighting, of which a sample line is

```
'function' 'bg=green'
```

I could also have here, for example

```
'function' 'bg=blue,fg=yellow'
```

However, I want to take advantage of my 256 color terminal (konsole in my case), in which case I would have thought that something like

```
'function' 'bg=$FG[021],fg=$FG[196]'
```

for example, would work, given that I have previously loaded the spectrum module.

But I can't get this to work.  I've checked that `tput colors` returns 256, and that the command

```
 echo "$FG[214]Hello, World"
```

gives me an orange output.

Anyway, whether I use spectrum or not, I'd like more control over my syntax highlighting, and to be able to use 256 colors.  Any advice would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the color index here like below:

```
'function' 'bg=21,fg=196'
```

`zsh-syntax-highlighting` gets the ability to specify colors from the zsh's [Character Highlighting](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Character-Highlighting) rather than ANSI escape sequences directly. This zsh manual describes a 'fg=*colour*' as below:

> fg=*colour*
>   　The foreground colour should be set to colour, a decimal integer or the name of one of the eight most widely-supported colours.

We can use the color index rather than ANSI escpape sequences which spectrum module stores on `$FG[...]`.

Comment: Thank you - I didn't know I could just specify a color by index number.  All good now!

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
export TERM='xterm-256color'
```